# javascript: convert seconds to months

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am using the following script to do a countdown.

```
function startCountdown() {
    var countdownDate = new Date("9/13/2013 12:00 AM");
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var dateDifference = new Date(countdownDate - currentDate);
    var seconds = dateDifference.valueOf() / 1000;
    CountBack(seconds);
}

function CountBack(seconds) {
    var DisplayFormat = "DAYS days and HOURS hours";
    DisplayFormat = DisplayFormat.replace("DAYS", (Math.floor(seconds/86400)) % 100000);
    DisplayFormat = DisplayFormat.replace("HOURS", (Math.floor(seconds/3600)) % 24);
    $('span.countdown').html(DisplayFormat);
}

startCountdown();
```

How can I show the months left too? (I want like: 3 months, 29 days and 3 hours)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this simple nice function. Check out the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h8J8L/14/)**:

```
var cc = new Date("9/13/2012 12:00 AM"),
    c = new Date();

function timeDifference(d, dd) {
    var hour = 60 * 60 * 1000,
        day = hour * 24,
        month = day * 30,
        ms = Math.abs(d - dd),
        months = parseInt(ms / month, 10);    

    ms = ms - months * month;    
    var days = parseInt(ms / day, 10); 
    ms -= days * day;
    var hours = parseInt(ms / hour, 10);   
    ms -= hours * hour;

    return [
        months + " months",
        days + " days",
        hours + " hours"
    ].join(", ");
};

document.body.innerHTML += timeDifference(cc, c) + "<br />";
```

Comment: would this take into account the 30 days, 31 days in a month etc ?

Comment: I changed the countdownDate to a 2012 date, and it blew up - http://jsfiddle.net/h8J8L/1/

Comment: I am not the OP. :) I was just understanding this code. Looks really neat

Comment: @alex23 Hey Alex, thank you! But your code just show the month, ignoring "days" and "hours". Is there some way to show "X months, Y days and N hours"?

Comment: @alex23 I think something is wrong here... I am receiving "9:2:78:23" - http://i.imgur.com/V3XGzuM.png

Comment: @alex23 Again, I think something is wrong. I see "9 months, 2 days, 78 hours" and 78 hours = 3,25 days, understand? (Btw, thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ageInTime(theAge) {
    if (theAge < 100 && theAge > 10)  {
        console.log(`${theAge} Years
        ${theAge * 12} Months
        ${theAge * 12 * 4} Weeks
        ${theAge * 12 * 4 * 7} Days
        ${theAge * 12 * 4 * 7 * 24} Hours
        ${theAge * 12 * 4 * 7 * 24 * 60} Minuts
        ${theAge * 12 * 4 * 7 * 24 * 60} Seconds`)
    } else {
        console.log("Age Out Of Range")
    }
}

ageInTime(110); 
ageInTime(38);
```