# Getting the time remaining until a date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to generate a string that says how long is left for a deadline but I can't figure out how you would work out the amount of time because of how inconsistent the calender is.

I want to output a string such as "1 month, 6 days and 10 hours remaining".

Here is what I have:

```
this.GetRemainingTimeString = function()
{
if(this.IsPastDeadline())
    return 'Past Deadline';

var str = '';
var diffMS = - this.EndDate - (new Date()).getTime();
var diff = new Date(diffMS);
var defDate = new Date(0);

var years = diff.getFullYear() - defDate.getFullYear();
var months = diff.getMonth();
var days = diff.getDate();

if(years > 0)
{
    str += years + ' Year' + (years != 1 ? 's' : '') + ' ';
}

if(months != 0)
{
    str += months + ' Month' + (months != 1 ? 's' : '');
}

if(days != 1)
{
    str += days + ' Day' + (days != 1 ? 's' : '');
}


    return str;
};
```

Comment: "1 month" does not mean much - could be 28,29,30,31 days.  Better go for years, days and hours.

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530474/javascript-convert-seconds-to-months

Comment: @CFrei and how long is a year? 365 days or 366 days?

Comment: @aL3891 I don't know how to generate the string I put at the top

Comment: Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).  It's a cool JS library for date/time.

Comment: @dcclassics Awesome .from did exactly what I wanted. Is there any way I could do that without the library, I only need that function and it seems a waste of 10kb.

Comment: Sure, the point was for ease of use :)

CHeck this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16530525/2002412

Comment: Although in my experience, I've used `Just Now`, `A few minutes ago`, `N minutes ago`, `N hours ago`, `Yesterday`, then used the actual date / time.  It gets funky as @CFrei stated after a couple days.

Comment: That is awesome, exactly what I wanted, thankyou so much. I would do that but I'm counting down not up (EG: '5 minutes remaining'). If you want to post that as an answer I can mark it as accepted for you.